How MATLAB makes the distinction between P-Cores and E-Cores?
It is known that modern CPUs have both Performance cores (P-cores) and efficiency cores (E-cores), different types of CPU cores that have different purposes and are designed for different tasks. P-cores typically have higher clock speeds and designed for high-performance tasks, while E-cores operate at lower clock speeds and focus on energy-efficient processing.
In MATLAB, maxNumCompThreads returns the current maximum number of computational threads. Currently, the maximum number of computational threads is equal to the number of physical cores on your machine.
How MATLAB makes the distinction between P-Cores and E-Cores ?
Brahim @ Singapore

I suspect it depends on the OS to some extent. Before Win11 the E&P core support wasn't really there. I'd hazard a guess that it uses E-core(s) for the user interface and anything that is remotely CPU bound goes to a P-core. I also expect that due to hyper threading MATLAB maxNumCompThreads default may be more than physical cores and less than twice that number. I find using around 1.6x physical cores about optimal for my problems - using more than that saturates memory bandwidth and just generates extra heat without any increase in performance.

Are you asking how it classifies a core as P or E after checking its cpuid results or something?  On current systems, the max MHz for E cores is lower than P cores, so that's one common way to check.  The model/family info may be the set to report the same because some anti-piracy software assumed real systems were homogeneous, so it's not as easy as just looking at model/family.  Related: How to detect P/E-Core in Intel Alder Lake CPU? / How to detect E-cores and P-cores in Linux alder lake system?

Are you wondering what would happen on a CPU with only E-cores, no P-cores, like Alder Lake N, or Xeon 6 Sierra Forest?  Or a VM that had only E cores?  IDK, hopefully it doesn't report 0 in that case :P

If the question is about "how MATLAB maximize it's performance with the knowledge of a hybrid structured CPU", then part 1 helps with it:
Disclaimer: All credits goes to the MathWorks Support Team, I just copy and pasted it from here.
Parallel Computing Toolbox can use both types of cores. MATLAB will rely on the operating system to schedule processes across the available cores, whether they are performance-oriented or designed for efficiency. However, it's important to note that while PCT can utilize both performance (P) and efficiency (E) cores, the best practice for computational tasks is to start with a number of parallel workers equivalent to the number of physical P cores. This is because P cores are akin to traditional physical cores in terms of computational capability, while E cores are optimized for power-saving and less intensive tasks.
From R2024a onwards Parallel Computing Toolbox's local 'Processes' profile will use a number of default workers equal to the number of P cores on the machine.
This can be altered by the same steps in the link at the bottom.
Windows Power Plan
If you are using Windows, you may wish to look at adjusting your Windows Power Plan. If this is set to ‘balanced’ then Windows may deprioritise background or unselected applications so they will only run on the E cores of the system. Setting the power plan to ‘High Performance’ should cause the Intel Thread Director to be able to select which workloads are best suited to each core.
Performance Expectations
You may still see performance gains when including efficiency cores in your parallel computations, but the scaling may differ from performance cores. The actual performance improvement will depend on the nature of your code and the specific tasks being executed. In some cases, efficiency cores can handle less demanding parallel tasks effectively, allowing the performance cores to focus on more intensive computations.
If you wish to change the default number of cores used:
See also this Answer for further details on changing the number of cores leveraged by Parallel Computing Toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2042101-how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-matlab-workers-inside-parallel-computing-toolbox-to-use-all-the-cor
Part 2. If the question is really about "How MATLAB estimate the exact number of P-cores and E-cores on a given system" Then it is very hard to tell because MATLAB is a closed source software package that targets multiple OS and hardware platforms, and they constantly make changes under the hood without notifications. One speculative method might be the "GetSystemCpuSetInformation" function on Windows, which returns a _SYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION type of structure:
typedef struct _SYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION {
  DWORD                    Size;
  CPU_SET_INFORMATION_TYPE Type;
  union {
    struct {
      DWORD   Id;
      WORD    Group;
      BYTE    LogicalProcessorIndex;
      BYTE    CoreIndex;
      BYTE    LastLevelCacheIndex;
      BYTE    NumaNodeIndex;
      BYTE    EfficiencyClass;
      union {
        BYTE AllFlags;
        struct {
          BYTE Parked : 1;
          BYTE Allocated : 1;
          BYTE AllocatedToTargetProcess : 1;
          BYTE RealTime : 1;
          BYTE ReservedFlags : 4;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
      } DUMMYUNIONNAME2;
      union {
        DWORD Reserved;
        BYTE  SchedulingClass;
      };
      DWORD64 AllocationTag;
    } CpuSet;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} SYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION;

where the EfficiencyClass field could provide related information. However this is not a definitive answer and there might never be one.

This is relevant but doesn't really answer the question of how.  For example, it doesn't tell us what would happen on a CPU with only E-cores, no P-cores, like Alder Lake N, or Xeon 6 Sierra Forest.  Or a VM that had only E cores on a normal desktop.  Or if run on hypothetical future machines with different kinds of P and E cores, whether it would still detect the E cores as E cores.  (Like on AMD where their Zen4c cores are just Zen4 but with smaller cache and tuned for lower max clock speed.)

@PeterCordes Yes, it does answer the question. MATLAB makes no distinction. "MATLAB will rely on the operating system to schedule processes across the available cores." That is, it is the OS that decides where each process runs. MATLAB just launches the processes.

@CrisLuengo: I guess that answers one possible reading of the question, like "does MATLAB pin its threads to the P-cores to match its default thread count?"  (i.e. is thread pinning part of the distinction it makes).   And this is answering "no".  That isn't what I thought it was asking, which as I commented under the question, I think it's asking how MATLAB figures out which cores are which so it can count the number of physical P cores in the first place.  This answer doesn't answer that at all.  OS thread APIs don't currently report E vs. P core counts; they predate such CPUs.

@PeterCordes You're right, you can interpret the question in that way too. It seems that R2024a and onwards can figure out how many P cores there are. But it still doesn't need to know which cores those are.

@PeterCordes I don't think MATLAB would disclose that information so I fill the gap with some guesswork. I understand you have been following this topic for a while, so feel free to edit the answer.

If someone had a real-world problem that depended on E-core detection, support might answer with details. Otherwise some reverse-engineering might shed some light, for example strace on Linux or an equivalent tool on Windows can trace what system-calls a process makes.  But that would only tell us if a Windows version of MATLAB calls GetSystemCpuSetInformation at all, not whether it checks the EfficiencyClass field in the output.  Interesting that such a field exists at all; the docs mention ARM bit.LITTLE which predates Alder Lake's implementation of the same idea by several years.
